# Что будет, если на spring event не найдется listener?

Tags: java, spring, события

Есть регистратор собственных событий:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisher;

@Autowired
private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;
 ...
 {publisher.publishEvent(e);}
```

Есть набор листенеров на аннотациях:

```
@Component
public class MyListener {
 @EventListener
 public void someMethod(SpecificEvent e){
     ...
 }
}
```

Собственные ивенты наследуются от общего абстрактного, причем могут приходить из сторонних систем.

Собственно вопрос: если в регистратор попадет event, для которого не определен @EventListener - что произойдет и как такую ситуацию предотвратить программно (надо перенаправить в обработчик по-умолчанию)? Ссылки на описания как устроен spring event "под капотом" приветствуются.

Comment: Ничего не будет, событие просто не обработается.

Comment: Логично, но хочется понять как это отслеживать. Ну и быть уверенным, что нигде съеденных ресурсов не подвисает.